# AngularJS directive test fails - Why "element" has the a wrong value?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Given the following directive, could one explain why the following test fails? <kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/hsAeXycsfIqSiRoXpzDO?p=preview)</kbd>

**DIRECTIVE**

```
angular.module('plunker').directive('maybeLink', function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
      maybeLink: '=',
      maybeLinkText: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.$watch('maybeLinkText', function(newVal) {
        scope.text = newVal.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
      });

      scope.$watch('maybeLink',function() {
        var newEl;
        if (scope.maybeLink) {
          newEl = $compile('<a href="#">{{ text }}</a>')(scope);

        } else {
          newEl = $compile('<span>{{ text }}</span>')(scope);
        } 
        element.replaceWith(newEl);
        element = newEl;
      });

    } 
  };
});
```

**TEST**

```
describe('Directive: maybeLink', function() {
  var scope, $compile;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('plunker');

    inject(function($rootScope, _$compile_) {
      scope = $rootScope;
      $compile = _$compile_;
    });
  });

  function compile(html) {
    var element = $compile(html)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    return element;
  }

  it('should create a link when link URL exists', function() {
    scope.myLinkText = 'Great Video';
    scope.myLinkURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYEDA3JcQqw';

    var element = compile('<span maybe-link="myLinkURL" maybe-link-text="myLinkText"></span>');

    console.log(element[0].outerHTML); // => <span maybe-link="myLinkURL" maybe-link-text="myLinkText" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope"></span> 
    console.log(element.html());       // => (empty string)

    expect(element.text()).toBe('Great Video');
    expect(element.find('a').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you change `element.replaceWith(newEl);` to `element.append(newEl);` in the directive code, the test will pass. So what you need is pass the template in the test with an additional HTML wrapper.

So just wrap the template in the test code with `div` or what ever valid HTML element like this, the test should pass.

```
var element = compile('<div><span maybe-link="myLinkURL" maybe-link-text="myLinkText"></span></div>');
```

Comment: I'm really interested to know why this wrapping in necessary. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's because the reference the variable is pointing:
If we do foo = $compile("<maybeLink />") , foo will keep the reference to the old object, the one that was replaced.
If we do foo = $compile("<div><maybeLink /></div>"), foo will contain the reference to the <div> element. In this case, we will try to compile the first div and then the maybeLink. As replaceWith is done at maybeLink level, foo will always contain the reference to the div object. Speculating what could happen, we may lose the reference to the maybeLink object if we had a link function in the div.