# Testing replaceWith in directive with jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

Can anyone please tell me on how I can test directives whose element is replaced? I am facing an issue where when I  pass in a directive element to be compiled in jasmine, the compiler doesn't return the replaced element but returns the uncompiled one instead. Is there any proper way to test these types of directives? Thanks.

My code:

```
var svgDirective = angular.module('svgDirective', ['adFactory']);
svgDirective.directive("svg", ['$compile', '$timeout', '$http', 'ad' , function ($compile, $timeout, $http, ad) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
      var refreshAd = function (id, missingFile) {
        ad.notProcessed(missingFile).then(function () {
          var timer = $timeout(function () {
            refreshAd(id, missingFile)
          }, 2000);
          scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
            $timeout.cancel(timer);
          });
        }, function () {
          $http.get("/ads/" + id + ".json", {
            cache: false
          }).then(function (data) {
            if (data["data"]["svg_image"]["url"] && missingFile.split('.').pop() === 'svg') {
              elem.replaceWith("<object style='width: 75px;height:75px' data=" + data["data"]["svg_image"]["url"] + "></object>");

            }
            if (data["data"]["json_image"]["url"] && missingFile.split('.').pop() === 'json') {
              scope.ad.json_image.url = data["data"]["json_image"]["url"];
            }
          });
        });
      };


      if (scope.ad.is_svg_processed) {
        elem.replaceWith("<object style='width:75px;height:75px' data=" + scope.ad.svg_image.url + "><object>");
      } else {
        refreshAd(attr.class, scope.ad.svg_file);
      }

      if (!scope.ad.is_json_processed) {
        refreshAd(attr.class, scope.ad.json_file);
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

My test code:

```
describe("svg Directive", function(){

  var $compile, $scope, $templateCache, $timeout, $http, ad, element;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module("svgDirective"));
  beforeEach(module("templates"));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_,_$rootScope_,_$templateCache_,_$timeout_, _$http_, _ad_){

    $compile = _$compile_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $templateCache = _$templateCache_;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    $http = _$http_;
    ad = _ad_;

    element = '<svg></svg>'


  }));

  it("should show svg images for ads whose svg images are processed", function(){

    $scope.ad = {is_svg_processed:true,is_json_processed:true, svg_image:{url:"https://dicerocket.s3.amazonaws.com/ad/svg_image/622/1_1398608090_28021105597015874837455612979611260004.svg"}};
    element = $compile(element)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();

    console.log(element);

  });

});
```

When `console.log(element)` I am getting `<svg class="ng-scope"></svg>` instead of the object tag that I want replaced. Can anyone tell me why?

The directive runs correctly but I can't seem to test it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898115/424783

In summary, you need to wrap the directive in other element like a DIV

```
element = '<div><svg></svg></div>';
```